# Windows 10 can't select most resolutions once external monitor is connected

Tags: laptop, graphics-card, display, multiple-monitors, resolution

My laptop's native resolution is 1920 x 1080 59Hz, my external monitor's (Yiynova tablet) native resolution is 1024 x 600 60Hz. The tablet can only work if the displays are duplicated or if it's the only display, extending workspaces doesn't work well for the pen.

By default the laptop has a dozen or so resolutions it can use, however when I plug in the tablet and duplicate screens, only three remain: 1920 x 1080 (Recommended), 1024 x 600, 800 x 600. The recommended resolution doesn't work well because the pen doesn't track to it correctly, although it looks fine. Same for 800 x 600.

So I must choose 1024 x 600 to get the ratio just right for the pen to work correctly. (Also, if I display only the tablet monitor, the other two options disappear and only this one remains.)

My problem is, it's a bit small for the programs I use. So I created a custom resolution in the Intel Graphics settings, 1536 x 900. I figured it should work since it's smaller than the recommended resolution that still  technically works with the tablet. However, when I plug it in, the option disappears too...

Any way to keep it there to use with the tablet?

Here's a crude mock-up image:
[image]

Comment: You need to use the device's native resolution.

Comment: But it can use the laptop's native resolution just fine. Even one other resolution. So why not a scaled up version of its own native resolution?

Comment: Native resolution is the physical number of pixels the screen is composed of. LCDs native resolution is a physical property, and any deviance from it is going to cause problems. Some LCDs can scale, but when you're dealing with touch devices, the rules may be different and support for non-native resolutions is even less likely.

Comment: I get that, but it still supports 800 x 600 for some reason. It technically shouldn't support that or the laptop's native resolution which is much bigger than its own, right? Is there some thing I can tweak somewhere to take advantage of this?
Actually, if I remember right, it has other resolutions it can use once connected to my other laptop. I couldn't even get it to use its own native resolution without adding it to that laptop first.

Comment: Okay, so I thought to open up the tablet's program to look at the resolution settings. I didn't before because there's no way to change them from it. However, I noticed once I set the laptop's res to 1920 x 1080, the program says it's at 1536 x 864... I wish I could tweak the height some, but all the options are greyed out no matter what! So frustrating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not too long ago I figured out that if I change the full resolution (1920 x 1080) to the size 100% instead of its automatic (Recommended) size 125%, the Yiynova works at that resolution with perfect pen tracking. The tablet now works at maximum resolution, even bigger than what I was originally trying to force it to.

I was both happy and incredibly frustrated by once again overlooking such a simple solution...